# Set session cookie in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

I Try to use session on my site.
Only my chrome doesn't work. When I Open my site, I get always new SET-Cookie with new PHPSESSID. (this is not SSL site and I'm not using incognito mode)

**PHP CODE:**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 'xyz';
```

**Response Header:**

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 19 Feb 2018 15:21:03 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=t3t7efdk9ljpt1vrn62rmv2647; path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

**Request Header:**

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie: phpMyAdmin=of4b155ds75s045438t7ck352cgmfoae
DNT:1
Host: example.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36
```

After reload page - 
In Request Header - there is not 'PHPSESSID' cookie. Other cookies work fine.

I test the same site on Microsoft Edge - and everything was ok.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `$_SESSION['name']` does not set the name of your session that will be used in cookies.

Your session name is `PHPSESSID`. This is set during session_start from the PHP [session.name](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) setting. This is what will be used in your cookies.

Your request headers showing `Cookie: xyz=va;` will not resume the session you started. They should be as per the response headers.

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=t3t7efdk9ljpt1vrn62rmv2647
```

Comment: Using this `$_SESSION['name'] = 'xyz';` I Mean that, I want to save some data to session. I know cookie name is 'PHPSESSID' and this is not in Request Header, and I know that it should be. It doesn't work only with chrome, if you can see there is `set-cookie: PHPSESSID=...` but chrome doesn't use this cookie in request headers

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your question and remove the confusing parts. i.e. that you are setting a session key called "xyz" and that happens to match a cookie in your request headers. If these two things are unrelated and inconsequential, then don't include them

Comment: Ok, I remove XYZ from Cookie - I mean only that setCookie for other key than PHPSESSID works on chrome

Comment: I can't reproduce any such problem in chrome using your exact Response headers over HTTP. Are you sure your browser isn't set to block cookies? Any other blocking extensions installed? Does the cookie show up in the devtools Application>Cookies panel?